# mpirun launching a runtime script for thread binding

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, cpu

Running a program in a MPI process, which exec file is `myapp_mpi`. The command line below launches the app correctly

```
mpirun --bind-to none -np 128 myapp_mpi apprun -resethway -noconfout -nsteps 8000 -s benchData.tpr -cpo state.cpt -e ener.edr -dlb no -pin off -v
```

I now wish to constrain the thread binding with a script `pin.sh`. The command line below would then produce an error.

```
mpirun --bind-to none -np 128 pin.sh myapp_mpi apprun -resethway -noconfout -nsteps 8000 -s benchData.tpr -cpo state.cpt -e ener.edr -dlb no -pin off -v
```

I get the following error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open MPI tried to fork a new process via the "execve" system call but
failed.  Open MPI checks many things before attempting to launch a
child process, but nothing is perfect. This error may be indicative
of another problem on the target host, or even something as silly as
having specified a directory for your application. Your job will now
abort.

  Local host:        machine001
  Working dir:       /home/user/myapp/bin
  Application name:  /home/user/myapp/bin/pin.sh
  Error:             Exec format error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun: Forwarding signal 18 to job
mpirun: Forwarding signal 18 to job
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to start the specified application as it encountered an
error:

Error code: 1
Error name: (null)
Node: machine001

when attempting to start process rank 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
125 total processes failed to start
```

File locations are good, a priori. Any clue ?

Comment: You say `pin.sh` but mpirun complains about `pintocore.sh`. Strange.

Comment: Corrected, this was a renamed typo

Comment: Is the execute permision set on on your script?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx  1 user user       727 Aug 12 09:46  pin.sh

Comment: Can you mpirun a script that only does a "hello world"?

Comment: Can you manually run `/home/user/myapp/bin/pin.sh` on `machine001`?

Comment: yes, yes ... ...

Comment: Does your `pin.sh` script starts with `#!`? if yes, what is the first line? then what does `file <interpretor>` says? is this the same architecture than `machine001` ?